# xamarin.forms Sharing Image AND text (body, not title)

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am using this sharing function:

```
 public static async void ShareImageAndText(string text, string image)
        {
            var fn = "pic.png";
            var file = Path.Combine(FileSystem.CacheDirectory, fn);
            File.WriteAllBytes(file, Convert.FromBase64String(image));

            await Share.RequestAsync(new ShareFileRequest()
            {
                Title = text,                      
                File = new ShareFile(file)
            });
        }
```

This shares an image to whereever I please, but the text "title" only appears if I share to email. If I share to whatsapp for instance, it will only give the image. But since I also want to share a text with an uri in it, this option doesnt work.

Who knows how to share a file AND a text in the same request?

Thanks

Comment: Is this happening on iOS or Android or both?

Comment: This is happening on both. It makes sense, since it should be "body" instead of "title" but there is no body property.

Comment: Tbh I don't even know if it's supported on all platforms. Looking at [the code](https://github.com/xamarin/Essentials/tree/main/Xamarin.Essentials/Share) the `Title` also doesn't seem to be mapped to anything for a `ShareFileRequest`.

Comment: Im fine with Droid and iOS. How would you go on about that?

Answer (score 0):

Having the same problem, I was unable of resolving it using the Xamaring.Essentials.Share. So, I created in my Xamarin Forms App a Page with the Image and Text that I need to send, and take a screenshot of it using Screenshot https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/screenshot and saving it to File. Then just send it.

```
 //Take a screenshot from this page to a file
 string path = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
 var File_Path = System.IO.Path.Combine(path, "Screenshot.png");
 var screenshot = await Screenshot.CaptureAsync();
 var stream = await screenshot.OpenReadAsync(ScreenshotFormat.Png);
 using (var fileStream = System.IO.File.Create(File_Path))
 {
      stream.Seek(0, System.IO.SeekOrigin.Begin);
      stream.CopyTo(fileStream);
 }

 await Share.RequestAsync(new ShareFileRequest
 {
     Title = "Some Title",
     File = new ShareFile(File_Path)
 });
```

Comment: But this leads to the same problem: It shares an image, but not title...

Comment: But if you design that screen properly, your image may contains the Title and text that you need to send inside the image

Comment: Oh, i get it lol. I dont think my client would wanna live with that xD